# How to draw a “Snip diagonal corner rectangle” with css?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to bring a modal up with snip diagonal corner rectangle shape. It was a rectangle with corners cut off on bottom right corner and top left corner. This shape is part of Microsoft office shape.

Is there anyway to get the modal with this shape?

Update: Image [Fourth image from top](https://pptcrafter.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/brick1.png?w=268&h=405)

JS script to open modal:

```
function clickhere(){
document.getElementById(‘modal’).style.display = “block”;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class=“modal” id=“modal”>
<div class=“modalborder”>
.....
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal{
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(0,82,194);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.modalborder{
background-color: #e6ebef;
margin: auto auto auto auto;
width: 70%;
height: 45%;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

I want the border to appear as the 4th image from the top of the linked image.
Can some one help?

Comment: So basically you're asking how to draw a triangle in CSS? Or a trapezoid? You'll need to provide a picture of what you're trying to achieve, and your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge No, I want something like this https://pptcrafter.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/brick1.png?w=268&h=405

Comment: @ObsidianAge fourth image from top!

Comment: @ObsidianAge updated the requested details in the original question. Sorry was typing from phone, so was not able to update full modal details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <div class="shape"> </div>  


     .shape{
          background: #f00;
          width: 300px;
          padding: 110px;
          margin: 200px;
          position: relative;
      }
      .shape:before{
            content: "";
            top:0;
            right: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            border-left: 100px solid red;
            border-top: 50px solid transparent;
            border-right: 0px solid red;
            height: 0;
            width: 100px;
            padding: 85px;
            transform: rotate(-180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
      }
      .shape:after{
          content: "";
          top: 0%;
         left: 100%;
          position: absolute;
            border-left: 100px solid red;
            border-top: 50px solid transparent;
            border-right: 0px solid red;
            height: 0;
            width: 100px;
            padding: 85px;
      }
```

Comment: I get a Square on right side and a rectangle with a diagonal cut at the top left corner and no cut at the bottom right corner, when tried in IE11, but works fine on chrome, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/VikramMohan/uwk09dj3/1/ Can you help in viewing it in IE?

Comment: @vikram mohan just add the vendor prefixes for all browsers and it will works .use the edit version